# UWP C#: How to make a framework element to full window mode

Tags: uwp, media-player, fullscreen, uwp-xaml

I am writing a uwp app that has multiple frameworkEelements. When a button is clicked, I want one of the FrameworkElement(In my app it is a usercontrol) to be in full window. I don't want a new window to be launched.
(Similar to the behavior of media player element going to full window)

This seems trivial but I can't get it working. I tried the following and this seems to make the element go to full screen but there are issues like I am not getting button click events(app seems to be unresponsive sometimes)

```
private async void onSelectFullWindow(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryEnterFullScreenMode();
    Window.Current.Content = customElementToBeFullScreen; 
}
```

I want to know in general how do we make an element enter full-screen mode without opening a new window.

Comment: The method you used to make an element enter full-screen mode is correct. About this "but there are issues like I am not getting button click events" error, what do you mean? Do you mean the button click events in userControl won't be triggered in the full window mode? Or the onSelectFullWindow event can't be triggered? Can you show the related xaml code?

Comment: I am not getting events for Button click in full window mode. But this is not consistent. (seen sometimes). I have a user control element which are added to a grid through code. I see this issue only when I create the user element but do not add in the grid but instead set the user control directly in Window.Current.Content
Issue is not seen if I add the user control in grid and then later add to Window.Current.Content
var customUserElement = new CustomUserElement(); 
// grid.Children.Add(customUserElement);  //Uncomment: issue is not seen
Window.Current.Content = customUserElement;

Comment: As a continuation of above comment, I am not why the issue isn't seen if I add the custom element to a grid before setting to full screen.But for now the below code works
public void setFullScreen(bool isFullScreen)
{
    if (isFullScreen)
    {                
         pageBackup = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
         Window.Current.Content = customEl;  //before this function call customEl is added to a grid
     }
      else
      {
           Window.Current.Content = pageBackup;
            updateView(); //customEl is updated back in grid
        }
    }

Comment: So do you mean when you use setFullScreen() method, this issue won't occur?

Comment: why aren't you using
    Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
    rootFrame.Navigate(...)
?

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT Yes the issue won't occur when I use setFullScreen

Comment: @user1422101I tried this. But the navigation headers are seen in full screen mode. I want only the particular user control to be visible in full screen.